# pass a variable inside bear token

Tags: php

I can pass the bearer token using the following code in my php script:

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer blablablabla',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

The above succeeds connecting.
The problem is I have to pass the above token (blablabla) which comes from variable called $token.

I tried to pass like the below

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer $token',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

But the above did not work and got denied. Therefore $token is not passed inbetween single quotes with space.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double quotation marks to pass a variable into a string. For example:

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

Or you can use concatenation:

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the string by a double quote.

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret the following escape sequences for special characters and vars. On the other-hand the single quote is the simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character ').

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

Alternatively you can use `.` symbol to concatenate.

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
);
```

[**Reference**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).